# Paypal shipping calculator connection with cart66

Tags: php, html, paypal

I set all shipping calculations within my paypal account and is working fine with the paypal buy now buttons I created. I moved to cart66 and need to be able to continue using paypal's shipping calculator. I do not want to use cart66's shipping calculator. At the moment however many product I select or whatever zipcode I put it I keep getting same price 0$ for shipping. How do I fix this?

Actual website;
http://goo.gl/Qofvd9 <-- explicit (consider yourself warned)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site is using Express Checkout.  With Express Checkout, your cart has to pass over the shipping.  You can't use your shipping profile within your PayPal account.  The PayPal account shipping would only work for Website Payments Standard buttons, not Express Checkout.  You may have to poke around in your shopping cart to determine where you need to set up shipping profiles in there.